# K[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz) not UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove its not UFD.
I started by assuming

x=ab in K[v] , where v=v(xw-yz)
then 
x-ab=(xw-yz)f, for some f in K[x,y,w,z]

I tried to say that deg of a, and b is less or equal 1, and then try to do a non-matching degree argument, but I could not see why a,and b should have deg leess or equal 1, how should I define degree in K[v].
Any help on how to prove this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, via proving that each x,w,y,z is irreducible. the issue is if I have x=ab in K[v], Can I talk about degree of a,b being less or equal one in K[x,y,z,w]

Comment: Because the ideal you divided with is homogeneous the quotient ring is [a graded ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring). Therefore the "obvious" definition of degree makes sense. Also because the ring is a domain (have you proved that?) the usual rule that *the degree of a product is the sum of the degrees of factors* holds.

Comment: Dear Jyrki, Thanks a lot, it makes more sense now, and can continue my argument. I have not proved its a domain, I am working on it. Now its much easier.

Comment: I have one only little detail. If the we have a, and b is of degree one in the ring R[x,y,z,t]/(xw-yz) how can pass this information to the original ring R[x,y,z,w]

Comment: The definition of "degree" in the quotient ring would be = "minimum of degrees of polynomials in the coset". You can probably use that lowest degree element in the coset.